# jQuery: How can I use a function argument as a function name inside my function?

Tags: jquery, function, variables, arguments, argument-passing

I have run into this problem a few times before so this time around I figured I would simply get some advice from those that know better.

I basically want to use my `function( argument )` as a function name inside this function.

Here is some code that I was trying to use:

```
$.fn.moveTo = function( myAction ) {

    $(this).myAction().fadeIn(400);

};
$('.currentElement').moveTo( 'next' ); // should become: $(this).next().fadeIn(400);
$('.currentElement').moveTo( 'prev' ); // should become: $(this).prev().fadeIn(400);
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to run?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$(this)[myAction]().fade(400)
```

Comment: @sdleihssirhc - i got lucky ;)

Comment: Thank you very much :) Works splendidly.

Answer (score 1):

Use subscript notation:

```
$(this)[myAction]().fadeIn(400);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(this)[myAction].apply($(this), []).fadeIn(400);
```

Comment: This is how Gary Busey does JavaScript.